# Vue app state not updating when Vuex store state mutates

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuex

I've been using Vue for a couple of months, I'm now trying to integrate Vuex with my app, but I'm not being able to update the state when Vuex store mutates.

I created a new app and implemented a simple count, just to see if it worked, but it still won't update the `count` when `store.count` is changed.
My test code is below.

`index.html`:

```
<div id="app">
    <template>
        <h1>{{count}}</h1>
        <button @click="add">Add 1</button>
    </template>
</div>
```

`index.js`:

```
import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.js';

import store from './store';

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    store,
    data: {},
    computed: {
        count: () => store.state.count
    },
    methods: {
        add: () => store.commit('add')
    }
});
```

`store.js`:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        count: 0
    },
    mutations: {
        add: (state) => state.count++
    }
});
```

I know `store.count` is being updated because I can see it in Vue dev tools. I just can't figure out why the `count` value won't update as well, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is most likely your import of `Vue` within `index.js`. Try changing it from:

```
import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.js';
```

To just:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
```

This would help to ensure that Vuex is registered correctly.

I created a project using `@vue/cli` with Vuex. Having the main/index import from `vue/dist/vue.js` instead of just `vue` failed to effectively register Vuex including being able to access `this.$store` in child components.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the problem is that, if I do that, I get following error:

```[Vue warn]: You are using the runtime-only build of Vue where the template compiler is not available. Either pre-compile the templates into render functions, or use the compiler-included build.```

Comment: Are you using @vue/cli or do you have a custom webpack configuration?

Comment: I'm using webpack.

Comment: This import is specifically causing the issue of Vuex failing to register effectively. You may want to post another question with your webpack configuration because you should be able to import from `vue` instead of `vue/dist`. If you try your code with a @vue/cli project, you can replicate the issue and resolution.

Comment: Ok, thanks. At least now I know where the problem is. :)

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the documentation about [actions](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html)

> Actions can contain arbitrary asynchronous operations.

In your case clicking on the `add`-button executes asynchronous code.
[Mutations](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html) on the other hand are synchronous which keep the values throughout your application persistent.
Mutations can be made through the `commit` statement, e.g. `store.commit("add")`.

**store.js**

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    count: 0
  },
  // Synchronous methods for modifying the values in the state.
  // They are handed a `state` from the store.
  mutations: {
    add: state => state.count++
  },
  // Asynchronous methods that can call mutation methods to mutate the state via commits.
  // They are handed a context of the `store`.
  actions: {
    add: store => store.commit("add")
  }
});
```

See full working example at [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/simple-vuex-example-8luhx).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I know how actions and mutations are supposed to work. It didn't work either way.